# How to check position of mouse poiner in R ? Is there any function for that?

Tags: r

How to check position of mouse pointer in R ? Is there any function for that ? I know about locator() etc. but body of that function doesn't contain any useful information for the question I've asked, is it possible for R to report position of mouse pointer not only in R window ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at getGraphicsEvent.  Try help(getGraphicsEvent).

Comment: unfortunatly : getGraphicsEvent "functions allow user input from some graphics devices (currently only the windows() and X11(type="Xlib") screen displays in base R). Event handlers may be installed to respond to events involving the mouse or keyboard." so it doestn't work outside R, even not outside R's window plot.

Comment: Would be nice to work outside R, though. I have a bunch of tasks I would be doing in pure R if that was possible.

Comment: >"Would be nice to work outside R, though. I have a bunch of tasks I would be doing in pure R if that was possible." me too I want to set some alarm in R which short when user move mouse = is sitting in the front of PC, and long when he is absent

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the cairoDevice package:

```
library(RGtk2)
library(cairoDevice)

da <- gtkDrawingArea()
asCairoDevice(da)
da$AddEvents(GdkEventMask["all-events-mask"])

w <- gtkWindow(show=FALSE)
w$add(da)
w$show()

hist(rnorm(100))

gSignalConnect(da, "motion-notify-event", function(w, e) {
  print(c(e$x, e$y))
  invisible(TRUE)
})
```